# Segmentation fault due to size() function of self-implemented data structure in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using a vector of vector in my A3 code. I sort the vector of vector's at insertion. I store my keys in the 0th index of each sub vector.

In my size method, I am trying to use the direct call for checking the size. The code below outlines my attempt. However, I get a segmentation fault on execution. Can anyone help me understand the reason for the same?

```
vector<vector<int>> pairs; //sorted in the insert method

int size(int key) const {
if( pairs[key].size() == 0 ) { return -1; }
else { return pairs[key].size() - 1; }
}
```

I have implemented the same successfully previously, however, it was a very inefficient solution using linear search. Here is the code for the same:

```
int size(int key) const
{
    for( int i=0; i<pairs.size(); i++)
    {
        if( pairs[i][0] == key )
        {
            return pairs[i].size() - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You use `new` in your `data` function but you never call `delete`. The caller should free up that information, or you should use the STL. [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: This is just a class definition. A class definition by itself does not create memory leaks. Look for http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Take a look at e.g. the [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) or [`std::string::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) functions. They return a pointer to their contained data *without* allocating memory that needs to be released. I'm sure your `data` function is supposed to work the same way.

Comment: I highly recommend [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), it can help detect and prevent memory leaks.

Comment: I think your `data()` function should be returning the `data()` call of whatever *vector* matches the key. You should not be creating an array to pass back.

Comment: I did. `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not enough to tell you what is happening, we can only make a guess.

I would say that your leak comes from the method data: you create a copy of the data and then return a pointer to this copy. It would be better to return an unique_ptr, so the memory is released automatically.

If you cannot change the definition of the method, then you could change the body of the method by this one:

```
int length = size(key);

if( length == -1 )
    return nullptr;

for( int i=0; i<pairs.size(); i++)
{
    if( pairs[i][0] == key )
    {
      return &pairs[i][1];
    }
}
return nullptr;
```

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with my updated question? Thanks!

Comment: Change this:
int size(int key) const {
if( pairs[key].size() == 0 ) { return -1; }
else { return pairs[key].size() - 1; }
}

Comment: Change this 

int size(int key) const {
if( pairs[key].size() == 0 ) { return -1; }
else { return pairs[key].size() - 1; }
}

for this


int size(int key) const {
pairs.resize(key+1);
if( pairs[key].size() == 0 ) { return -1; }
else { return pairs[key].size() - 1; }
}

Hope this helps.